# Retrofit Http gives api call successful but returns model elements as null

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I am using Retrofit version 2.3.0 with OkHttp 3.8.0. When I hit my api using a GET request it returns 200 as result but I am unable to access elements from the `Version` model.

```
APIService apiService = APIClient.getAPIService();

Call<Version> call = apiService.getVersionByVersionCode(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Version>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Version> call, Response<Version> response) {
                Version result = response.body();
                Log.e("TAG", "OnResponse " + result.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Version> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Failure ");
            }
        });
```

This is my `Version` class, and when I access the `versionName` or `version` elements of an instance, I get `null`:

```
package com.actovoice.model;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Version {

    @SerializedName("upgrade") int upgrade;
    @SerializedName("versionName") String versionName;
    @SerializedName("version") String version;

    public int getUpgrade() {
        return upgrade;
    }

    public void setUpgrade(int upgrade) {
        this.upgrade = upgrade;
    }

    public String getVersionName() {
        return versionName;
    }

    public void setVersionName(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

}
```

My Retrofit interface:

```
public interface APIService {

    @GET("apps/appType/ANDROID/version/{versionCode}")
    Call<Version> getVersionByVersionCode(@Path("versionCode") int versionCode);

}
```

Comment: Maybe the mapping is failing,plzz post ur raw response and Version class

Comment: also, put your retrofit interface

Comment: @Roy  pls check i have updated my question with version class and interface

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra  i have updated my question with version class and interface

Comment: Ok, looks like a parser error, put here all your api URL so i can make some tests.

Comment: Try to check your full url with versionCode in browser to see what it returns.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra  hosted on localhost like lan server unable to share u details

Comment: @Aroniez i have tested on browser and postman too it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Scalar Converter to your Retrofit instance like this:

```
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```